# how to compare the expected values with actual values using matlab's neural network toolbox?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have been using matlab's neural network toolbox lately for my research. I created some neural networks using fitting tool of this toolbox. Now I encountered a problem while testing the network with new data. Basically, I want to test the network with some new data, which do not have the same sample number as the network. For example, I have created the network with the input of 12x36 matrix (12 variables, 36 samples) and output of 1x36 vector (1 variable, 36 samples). Now, I want to get the results for a new data (12x11520 (12 variables and 11520 samples)). However, when I put this data into the network and get the results, I only get an output vector of 1x36 (1 variable 36 samples) while I was expecting to get the results as 1x11520 (1 variable and 11520 samples). I am using the below line to get the results from the neural network named as network.

output_estimate = network(input');

I also tried the line below to get the results but the result did not change.

output_estimate = sim(network,input');

Could you please help me understand this and get the output as the same sample length so that I can compare the expected and actual results for the new data.

Thank you very much in advance. 
Irem